# Remove a function on an "onclick" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript and I have a problem with function recalling, please See image Attached

[image: Image1]

but again i click on apply button it returns like

[image: image 2]

and repeating. this need to be stopped i have set timeout function  but thing is its not working. **So is this possible to destroy RegisterCapcha() and recall RegisterCapcha() in every onclick on apply button ???**

this form that show on apply button clicked

```
<form method="POST" id="careersForm" action="../php/emailsend.php enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
       <tr>
        <td>First Name  </td>
        <td><input type="TextBox" name="First_Name" class="applytext" requiredfield= "true" id="First_Name"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Last Name </td>
        <td><input type="TextBox" name="Last_Name" class="applytext" required id="Last_Name"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>E-mail  </td>
        <td><input type="email" id="emailid" name="email" class="applytext"  required onblur="validateEmail(this)" />
         <label id="valemailid" style="color:red;"></label>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Phone_No" name="Phone_No_No" class="applytext" placeholder="111-111-1111"; pattern="^[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}$" required onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="if(this.placeholder == '') { this.placeholder='(1-111-111-1111)'}" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/><span id="Phone_NoError" style="color:lightgray"><span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Attachment  </td>
        <td><input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="attachment" maxlength="50" class="applytext" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><br />
         <span id="lblError" style="color: red;"></span>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="applytable" >
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <p>
                            <label>
                                Enter the text shown below:
                                <input type="text" id="captchaText" onkeyup="javascript:EnableApply();" /></label></p>
                        <p id="captcha">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
         <input type="submit" id="submit" name="button" disabled="disabled" class="send-resume" value="SEND" onclick="return ValidateExtension()" style="margin-left:24%;">
         <input type="reset" value="RESET" onclick="clearForm()" style="margin-left:8%">
        </td>
       </tr>
      </form>
```

JS for captcha.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function EnableApply() {
        var OriginalCaptcha = $('#careersForm').data('captchaText');
        var userCapcha = $('#captchaText').val();

        if (OriginalCaptcha == userCapcha) {

            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        }
    }

    function RegisterCapcha() {
        $("#careersForm").clientSideCaptcha({
            input: "#captchaText",
            display: "#captcha",
            pass: function () { alert("Passed!"); return false; },
            fail: function () { alert("Failed!"); return false; }
        });
    }
</script>
```

i have set timeout function in  `<span id='close' onclick="function () { setTimeout(function () { RegisterCapcha(); }, 1000) } HideContent('job-apply'); return false;"></span>`

thanks in advance :)

Comment: You've created a anonymous function in onclick but you never call it.

Comment: can you mention that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not use client side captcha... however to answer your question

You may try below

```
function RegisterCapcha() {
        $("#captcha").html(''); //reset the generated captcha first
        $("#captchaText").val('');
        $("#careersForm").clientSideCaptcha({
            input: "#captchaText",
            display: "#captcha",
            pass: function () { alert("Passed!"); return false; },
            fail: function () { alert("Failed!"); return false; }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks bro it works..  can you explain me why my code not worked ?? @Patel

Comment: the registerCaptcha function was loading some TABLE elements generated by your clientSideCaptcha plugin. Calling the same function was appending the new captcha instead of replacing the previous one... so we just cleared the old HTML generated buy plugin & then the function will work just like called for the first time

Comment: thanks for your explanation. need little help...having trouble in call this registerCaptcha in onload. is this possible to load this registerCaptcha in onload ??  @Patel

Comment: simply call it in the $(document).ready(function(){ RegisterCapcha(); });